# AWS CLI - Create script to add my IP to security group

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to create a script to add my IP adress to AWS VPC security groups somthing like

```
>  aws ec2 modify-security-group-rules --group-id GROUPID\
> --security-group-rules SecurityGroupRuleId= RULEID\
SecurityGroupRule={IpProtocol:'tcp',FromPort:433,ToPort:433,CidrIpv4:'MYIP'}
```

But I keep getting different errors like -

> IpProtocol:tcp, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>

Can anyone please help figure out the correct syntax for this?

UPDATE:
I tried a new syntax that seems to work better

```
SecurityGroupRule={{IpProtocol=tcp},{FromPort=433},{ToPort=433},{CidrIpv4='IP'}}
```

But now I get a different error from AWS -

> Invalid value for portRange. Must specify both from and to ports with TCP/UDP.

UPDATE: For reference - Here's the workaround I used- (based on John Rotenstein answer)
Instead of modifying the rule I create a new one each time and save the rule ID so I can delete it next time I run the script

```
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
         --group-id GROUP_ID         \
         --security-group-rule-ids $(cat ruleid_1.txt)
       
    aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id GROUP_ID\
--ip-permissions "IpProtocol"="tcp","FromPort"=433,"ToPort"=443,"IpRanges"="[{CidrIp=$IP/32,Description=Shalev}]"|jq '.SecurityGroupRules[0].SecurityGroupRuleId' -r > ruleid_1.txt
```

Comment: Should be no space between `=` and `RULEID` and there should be a `,` instead of a space between that and `SecurityGroupRule`

Comment: Thank you for the answer
I did what you say but still got Invalid type for each parameter

Invalid type for parameter SecurityGroupRules[0].SecurityGroupRule, value: IpProtocol:tcp, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference - Here's the workaround I used- (based on John Rotenstein answer) Instead of modifying the rule I create a new one each time and save the rule ID so I can delete it next time I run the script

```
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`

aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
         --group-id GROUP_ID         \
         --security-group-rule-ids $(cat ruleid_1.txt)
   


aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id GROUP_ID\
--ip-permissions "IpProtocol"="tcp","FromPort"=433,"ToPort"=443,"IpRanges"="[{CidrIp=$IP/32,Description=Shalev}]"|jq '.SecurityGroupRules[0].SecurityGroupRuleId' -r > ruleid_1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Place value of parameter `--security-group-rules` inside quotes.
Both of the following seem to work for me (on Amazon Linux 2) -

- Using double quotes for complete value, with description in single quotes-

```
aws ec2 modify-security-group-rules --group-id sg-xxx
   --security-group-rules "SecurityGroupRuleId=sgr-xxx,SecurityGroupRule={Description='SSH
   Test1',CidrIpv4=x.x.x.x/32,IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=22,ToPort=22}"
```

- Using single quotes for complete value, with description in double quotes-

```
aws ec2 modify-security-group-rules --group-id sg-xxx
   --security-group-rules 'SecurityGroupRuleId=sgr-xxx,SecurityGroupRule={Description="SSH
   Test2",CidrIpv4=x.x.x.x/32,IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=22,ToPort=22}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to use the aws CLI to change a rule.
Requires "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules" permission.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-group-rules help

aws ec2 modify-security-group-rules --group-id sg--???????
 --security-group-rules SecurityGroupRuleId=sgr---???????,SecurityGroupRule={IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=22,ToPort=22,CidrIpv4=IP/32,Description="Regra
 Alterada"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I use to add my current IP address to a Security Group:

```sh
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name XXX --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $IP/32 --output text
```

It uses Akamai to retrieve my public IP address and then adds it to the desired Security Group.

Note that there is a limit to the number of rules in a Security Group, so eventually you will need to remove unused entries.

Comment: That's a good solution, I thought about it and i managed to add a new rule each time
But I don't want to add more and more rules, it's insecure and as you said there's a limit
This is why I wanted to modify the same rule
Any idea what might be the problem?
I have provided from port and to port and still get this error...

Comment: I think that 'modifying' the rules actually requires you to provide _all of the rules_. Whatever rules you specify become the _only_ rules.

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense,
Anyways I found a workaround this, I'll edit my question for reference

Comment: Please add the solution as an Answer rather than putting it in the Question. This makes it easier for future readers to find. You are permitted to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable for `SecurityGroupRule`.

Like:

```
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`

security_group_rules={CidrIpv4=$IP/32,IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=443,ToPort=443}

aws ec2 modify-security-group-rules \
    --group-id sg-123 \
    --security-group-rules SecurityGroupRuleId=sgr-123,SecurityGroupRule=$security_group_rules
```

It worked for me perfectly.

PS: This is my first answer here.